# Port-Stereotypes (CompositeStructure Diagram) are oversized even with Default-Size set

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, stereotype

i am developing a MDG Technology in Enterprise Architect, containing a UML-Profile.

I added a **Unit**-Stereotype (extending **UML:Component**) and a **Signal**-Stereotype (extending **UML:Port**).

After I added a Signal to Unit, the Signal is docked/anchored to the Unit - like a Port to a Component but it is extremely over sized (sth like 200x150). If i add a Port to the Unit the port keep its default size of 16x16. I tried to set the default size of Signal (_sizeX, _sizeY) but it wasnt helping.

Anyone has an idea to fix that problem?

EDIT: So i was able to reproduce this issue. When i set the "_metatype" - property of the Stereotype "Signal" (in the Profile-Definition-Package), a created Signal-Element anchored on a Unit was over-sized. If i remove the "metatype"-property the Signal-Element has the same behaviour, look and size like a Port-Element. I started a EA-Forum-Thread with this issue:
http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,30771.0.html

Kind regards, Erik

Comment: Can you confirm that you have checked "Element Size" when you save the profile?

Comment: Yes, i didnt unchecked it and it is checked by default

Comment: So i set the default size properties to 200x200 for the Unit-Stereotype. Creating a Unit will set its size to 200x200, but the Signal-Stereotype is still huge and its default size will not be applied when creating it :/

Comment: You're better off reporting this to Sparx.

Comment: Hm ok - thx till now. I will reply again if i've got more information about it